# Finding out running anaconda environment (not active on new processes or default) from within python

Tags: python, anaconda

What would be the best way to find the current anaconda environment from within python.

The problem is that it is not the default environment: for example calling

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['conda','info'])
```

gives me the wrong result (because it creates a new process, which has the default environment)

I run this using anaconda2 on win7 and running the code from pycharm, but in the best case scenario the solution should work "everywhere" or at least for anaconda

The location of the python.exe that was used to run my program would give the hint me that information, so using e.g.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
D:\Anaconda2\envs\py2\python.exe
```

is one option.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

print sys.version
```

Returns: (Something like)

```
2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: :S I am getting "2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]", but my environment is not the default, it is py2 (sys.executable gives me D:\Anaconda2\envs\py2\python.exe)